# How to handle first tab size on formatting?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I create an extension, that format vs editor tabs in custom ways, using ITextParagraphPropertiesFactoryService class. Everything works just fine, expect the fact, that when user enter new line, ITextParagraphPropertiesFactoryService doesnt affect to the new line

For simplifying the problem, I create a new MEF project, add a format provider like this

```
[Export(typeof(ITextParagraphPropertiesFactoryService))]
[ContentType("text")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Document)]
internal class ElasticTabstopsProvider : ITextParagraphPropertiesFactoryService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an ElasticTabstopsFormatters for
    /// the provided configuration.
    /// </summary>
    public TextParagraphProperties Create(IFormattedLineSource formattedLineSource, TextFormattingRunProperties textProperties, 
        IMappingSpan line, IMappingPoint lineStart, int lineSegment)
    {
        return new TextFormattingParagraphProperties(textProperties, 1);
    }
}
```

And it changes all tabs width from my editor to 1. Great! This is what I want. But now when I press Enter(new line) new cursor is set under Main, however I expect tab widths to be 1.

[image]

After I start typing it goes to expected position.

[image]

The question is, how can I set new line empty line tab size? 
I try to override `ISmartIndentProvider`, but seems vs ignore that value.

Debuger stops on breakpoint in method

```
int? GetDesiredIndentation(ITextSnapshotLine currentLine)
```

of `ISmartIndent`, but indent stays the same no matter what value I return...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two reasons why your ISmartIndentProvider's indent is being ignored:

First, there are lots of places with the current C# and VB language services where we explicitly set the caret position in response to certain keypresses. Enter is one of them. It's quite possible that in your scenario, we're explicitly setting the position. Short of disabling smart indenting in Tools > Options, there's nothing you can do to override that. Since you said you're getting a debugger hit in your ISmartIndentProvider, that's probably the issue here.

Second, if you're trying to define a ISmartIndentProvider for content type "text", yours won't get called if there is a language-specific provider. There's also another provider for "text" already (which calls the shimmed old language services) which might win over yours anyways.

To be honest, if you're trying to do something fancy where you don't want automatic indenting, then you really should just turn it off to ensure it's not getting in your way.

Comment: Thanks Jason for answer, than I don't see the reason of ISmartIndetProvider, it doesn't work even in the most simple case, but however could you please give a quick hint how to change tab indention to block and back to smart from code?

Comment: The interface exists to allow language services to specify how they want their indenting to work. It's not designed to allow extensions to override the language services' behavior. The API to change indenting for a specific language is [IVsTextManager.SetUserPreferences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextmanager.setuserpreferences.aspx). You might want to dig around online for the use, the APIs is a bit strange.

Comment: I see Jason, I will check about turning smart indentation off, but I think it is not my case, I need indention, but I need to set it to the correct position... are there any services to set current position myself?

Comment: You can always explicitly set the caret position through the editor APIs, but you'll find yourself fighting against the existing language services. Unless you turn off automatic indentation, you're going to be fighting with it -- changing logic in the manner you are doing is totally unsupported.

Comment: Thanks Jason, it is really cool to get an answer from VS team in SO on such a unusual question, honestly I didn't expect that I will get an answer..:)

Comment: Oh, many of us watch Stack Overflow for questions that we have some knowledge in. And to be honest, since Visual Studio extensibility isn't exactly the best documented thing in the world, sometimes the only way to get the info you need is through forums like this one.