# Convert virtual spaces into real tabs in Visual Studio sdk

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

My Visual Studio extension, is arranging Tab Sizes using [ITextParagraphPropertiesFactoryService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.formatting.itextparagraphpropertiesfactoryservice.aspx) interface. That class is doing a great job, and helps me to set tab widths for all existing lines, but I have a problem to set tab sizes for new virtual line. 
In other words, Visual Studio is setting caret position in `VirtualSnapshotPoint`, and converting it to real tabs only when user enters some symbols.

Now, Is it possible to force Visual Studio to create real tabs instead of virtual spaces? I try to create edit on view, and insert real '\t' symbols, but VS still converts it back to virtual... This happen for both, block and smart indent tab settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the behavior of blank lines being virtual space only is by design, and as best I know not changeable. If there's a specific problem with it, please update the question and we can go from there.

Comment: Thanks Jason, my extension set tab sizes for the real lines, the problem is that I can't set caret position to right place, when it go to virtual line. As soon as user starts typing, line become real, and extension fix tab size. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104387/how-to-handle-first-tab-size-on-formatting here is related question, but later I understand that the problem is related to virtual space not a smartindent

Comment: How are you setting the tab size? I guess maybe you're setting it in a way which is confusing the language services. You shouldn't be seeing any problems here.

Comment: I am using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textformatting.textparagraphproperties.tabs(v=vs.110).aspx this property to return tab sizes I want, the problem is that it doesn't work for virtual space, and on empty line cursor jump to "old" tab position, I want to control the sizes of virtual tabs too.

Comment: Oh I missed that detail...that's probably not the API you want to use. What are you actually trying to do? What is your overarching goal here?

Comment: I realize elastic tab stops, for visual studio, more details here http://nickgravgaard.com/elastictabstops/ ,and the only problem is setting caret position in a new virtual line. Since all tab sizes are dynamic, and virtual line doesn't support tab size arranging I guess

Comment: It may make sense, to create real tabs in OnCaretChanged, when the line is virtual, and to remove this tabs on file save..

Comment: Yeah, that might be your only option. Two warnings: when a caret is in virtual space, the position is simply a number of column width offsets from the physical point, so you'll have to do some non-trivial math to figure out what to insert. Furthermore, both the C# and VB formatters presume tab widths are a constant size across the entire file -- we do not check paragraph properties at all for tab alignment. So expect the formatters to do strange things...this quite simply isn't something we have ever thought to support.

Comment: I see Jason, thanks a lot for your support. I just create an edit, and insert virtuaspacecount/tabzie tabs in the line and this seems to work. I wonder also, how I can handle file saving without buffer change, because I don't want to change buffer I want to only fix file