# Convert virtual spaces into real tabs in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, indentation, visual-studio-extensions

In Visual studio when I create a newline it sets a caret to the indent that I want. However it's not a real tab indentation until I will type any character at line. So all my empty lines are still fully empty (without '\t') and i want to make VS to convert this virtual indentation into real tabs.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228444/convert-virtual-spaces-into-real-tabs-in-visual-studi-sdk) question is pretty close to what I want but in differense from that I don't write an extension but search an existing solution. Though if there's no other way i will have to do it.

Comment: So this is the "by design" behavior as I stated on that other question. If you want a different behavior, best choice is probably to send feedback through the feedback tools or on [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015).

Comment: @JasonMalinowski that question was asked 2+ years ago and for VS-2012 so I hoped some solution or workaround was appeared. But thanks for feedback.